# Printing to IP Address with Sockets and byte array printing blank pages on some printers

Tags: c#, sockets, pdf, printing

Does anyone have experience with sending a byte array to a printer? I am sending a pdf file directly to a printer's IP address and it prints on some printers and blank pages on other printers. Is this a printer driver issue?. Here is the code that prints:

```
 public class PrintService : IPrintService
  {
    ManualResetEvent connectDone;
    ManualResetEvent sendDone;

    /// <inheritDoc />
    public void PrintData(byte[] data, string printerName)
    {
      connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
      sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
      IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(printerName);
      IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
      Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
      client.NoDelay = true;

      try
      {
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(connectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();
        client.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), client);
        sendDone.WaitOne();
      }
      finally
      {
        // Shutdown the client
        this.shutDown(client);
      }
    }

    private void connectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
      // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
      Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

      // Complete the connection.
      client.EndConnect(ar);

      // Signal that the connection has been made.
      connectDone.Set();
    }
    private void sendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
      // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
      Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

      // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
      int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);

      // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
      sendDone.Set();
    }
    private void shutDown(Socket client)
    {
      client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
      client.Close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: we have a print preview option and it prints fine from there when the user can see the PDF in the web browser and can select all the print options. What are my alternatives?

Comment: In that scenario is probably the browser who is doing the rendering and not the printer.Your alternative is to render the PDF file in your application using a library or an external process (ghostscript, acrobat reader, etc).This topic has been discussed many times before here in SO.

Comment: I think you may be right with the printer because we tested on another printer and it worked. Just seems odd that the print preview works but the raw data did not. I am using `wkhtmltopdf.exe` to convert HTML the PDF.

Comment: I don't understand why that seems odd to you... as I said, the print preview is probably created by the printing application, are you using chrome for "testing" this printing scenario for example? Chrome is able to render PDF files on the screen out of the box.

Comment: odd wasn't the right choice of words haha, it really is not odd you are absolutely right. Frustrating is the right word.

Comment: @jmzagorski how can print a image throw your code.

Answer (score 1):

so after trying what felt like every other class (`PrintDocument`, `PrintServer`, `ProcessInfo` with `adobe/foxit`, copying the file directly to the printer, using `DLLImport[Kernetl32.dll]` to create a file at the port, using `GCHandle` and `pointers`), i focused my attention on messing with the printer settings. For the particular printer I had these were the steps that allowed my original code to work:

1. Turn off printer
2. Hold the check mark on the printer (usually located in plain sight) and right arrow key (next to the check mark in my case) and wait for `....` to fill the screen and disappear
3. Rest the base (not network) settings to the default (not sure if you have to do this step because the next step is when it worked)
4. Disable PPDS (Personal Printer Data Stream http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Printer_Data_Stream)

Answer (score 0):

Not all printers can render PDF files, and those that can might not even support all the possible versions of the PDF specification (a particular printer may not support complex transparencies for example).

One alternative is to render the PDF file from your application using a library (example: Amyuni PDF Creator .Net) and the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, or using an external process that can do the printing for you like ghostscript, acrobat reader, etc. (*Disclaimer: I currently work for Amyuni Technologies*).

Another alternative could be to restrict your application to Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 and implement a PDF to BITMAP conversion using [new APIs provided in these platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532207.aspx), then print the bitmap with the `PrintDocument` class, but note that these new APIs were designed to be used from Windows Store Applications and it might not be straight forward to use them outside of that environment.